# Unable to Remove Container Network

Tags: windows, docker

Since I upgraded Docker on my computer to beta27, I have been unable to run Windows containers using the default network. I get the following message:

```
docker: Error response from daemon: container xxx encountered an error during Start failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3): Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type.
```

I have uninstalled/removed everything (Docker for Windows, Hyper-V, the Containers feature, and files left over in C:\ProgramData\Docker) and then reinstalled everything but the issue persists.

I realised that the `nat` adapter was no longer present in Hyper-V, but the `DockerNat` adapter was.

[This article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/management/container_networking) provides a script to reset the networking components but I am unable to remove the container network.

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ContainerNetwork

Name Id                                   Subnets         Mode SourceMac DNSServers DNSSuffix
---- --                                   -------         ---- --------- ---------- ---------
nat  12706897-fc71-41fc-9046-a7be0d01727e {172.16.0.0/12} NAT


PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-ContainerNetwork | Remove-ContainerNetwork

Confirm
Remove-ContainerNetwork will remove the container network "".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
Remove-ContainerNetwork : Unspecified error
At line:1 char:24
+ Get-ContainerNetwork | Remove-ContainerNetwork
+                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-ContainerNetwork], VirtualizationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.Containers.PowerShell.Cmdlets.RemoveContainerNetwork

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Remove-ContainerNetwork -Name nat

Confirm
Remove-ContainerNetwork will remove the container network "nat".
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
Remove-ContainerNetwork : Unspecified error
At line:1 char:1
+ Remove-ContainerNetwork -Name nat
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Remove-ContainerNetwork], VirtualizationException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : OperationFailed,Microsoft.Containers.PowerShell.Cmdlets.RemoveContainerNetwork

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

Is there a registry entry that I can delete to remove the network since it's failing to remove it via PowerShell?

Comment: Somewhat similar issue without any resolution yet.

`Get-ContainerNetwork` shows 4 networks. Still

`Get-ContainerNetwork | Remove-ContainerNetwork -force` says "Remove-ContainerNetwork : Element not found." for all of them

Answer (score 3):

Try removing the NAT network using the following:

```
Get-NetNat | Remove-NetNat
```

You can also try restarting HNS and docker

```
Restart-Service hns
Restart-Service docker
```

Comment: Remove-NetNat : The requested operation is not supported.
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-NetNat | Remove-NetNat
+              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MSFT_NetNat (In...2172be7db;0...):root/StandardCimv2/MSFT_NetNat) [Remove-NetNat], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 50,Remove-NetNat